# What is "string[] args" in Main class for?

Tags: c#

In C# the Main class has string[] args parameter.

What is that for and where does it get used?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

From the [C# programming guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx):

**The parameter of the Main method is a String array that represents the command-line arguments**

So, if I had a program (MyApp.exe) like this:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
  }
}
```

That I started at the command line like this:

```
MyApp.exe Arg1 Arg2 Arg3
```

The Main method would be passed an array that contained three strings: "Arg1", "Arg2", "Arg3".

If you need to pass an argument that contains a space then wrap it in quotes. For example:

```
MyApp.exe "Arg 1" "Arg 2" "Arg 3"
```

Command line arguments commonly get used when you need to pass information to your application at runtime. For example if you were writing a program that copies a file from one location to another you would probably pass the two locations as command line arguments. For example:

```
Copy.exe C:\file1.txt C:\file2.txt
```

Answer (score 36):

Further to everyone else's answer, you should note that the parameters are optional in C# if your application does not use command line arguments.

This code is perfectly valid:

```
internal static Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // Get on with it, without any arguments...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Besides the other answers. You should notice these args can give you the file path that was dragged and dropped on the `.exe` file.
i.e if you drag and drop any file on your `.exe` file then the application will be launched and the `arg[0]` will contain the file path that was dropped onto it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
}
```

this will print the path of the file dropped on the `.exe` file. e.g

> C:\Users\ABCXYZ\source\repos\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\bin\Debug\ConsoleTest.pdb

Hence, looping through the `args` array will give you the path of all the files that were selected and dragged and dropped onto the `.exe` file of your console app. See:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code sample above will print all the file names that were dragged and dropped onto it, See I am dragging 5 files onto my `ConsoleTest.exe` app.

[image: 5 Files being dropped on the ConsoleTest.exe file.]
And here is the output that I get after that:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 13):

For passing in command line parameters. For example `args[0]` will give you the first command line parameter, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

The args parameter stores all command line arguments which are given by the user when you run the program.

If you run your program from the console like this:

> program.exe there are 4 parameters

Your args parameter will contain the four strings: "there", "are", "4", and "parameters"

Here is an example of how to access the command line arguments from the args parameter: [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CmdLineArgs03212006232449PM/CmdLineArgs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You must have seen some application that run from the commandline and let you to pass them arguments. If you write one such app in C#, the array `args` serves as the collection of the said arguments.

This how you process them:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    foreach (string arg in args) {
       //Do something with each argument
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of the command line switches pass to the program.  E.g. if you start the program with the command "`myapp.exe -c -d`" then `string[] args[]` will contain the strings "-c" and "-d".

Answer (score 0):

It's an array of the parameters/arguments (hence args) that you send to the program. For example `ping 172.16.0.1 -t -4`

These arguments are passed to the program as an array of strings.

`string[] args` // Array of Strings containing arguments.