# How to read and set a permanent parameter for an exe

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm new to **C#** and **.net** and the question might be silly, but bear with me...
Any help or pointer in the right direction (if any) would be appreciated!

Let's say I have a C# console application.
I would like to be able to set (and read) a **permanent** parameter from cmd.
ex.

```
$ myApp.exe --setName="Bob"
```

```
$ myApp.exe --getName
> Bob
```

I would also like to be able to use the parameter in code.

```
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

should print out "Bob".

**Note**
The parameter being permanent means I want to set in once, not every time the app is launched.
So this doesn't work in my case
[What is "string[] args" in Main class for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552796/what-is-string-args-in-main-class-for)

Is there a way to achieve this? If so, can you link some docs if not give a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: " set ... a permanent parameter" - Then you need to save the value somewhere, e.g. into a text file (using JSON format, or whatever suits you) or into a database table. I agree that the duplicate link is incorrect @DavidG

Comment: @PeterB thank you. I think I can build on this.

Comment: @DavidG thank you also ... I can use the args as input and store the info as Peter suggests.

Comment: @PeterB It's either a dupe or needs to be closed for needing more focus. Either way, it's closed.